# How to find if a list contains a key in Interval

Tags: c#, intervals, sortedlist

I have a sorted list of elements of `<key,value>`.
The key is an unsigned int.

Is there any quick and efficient way in C# to determine if, given an interval , the list contains an element with a key in that interval?

Comment: A list doesn't have keys. You say you have a list "of elements of ." What are the elements? What have you tried?

Comment: for a fast key lookup, use `HashSet`

Comment: `Is there any quick and efficient way in C#`. Where is your slow and inefficient way so that we can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If your list contains whole positive numbers, then you could build your own function very easily using [LINQ Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Enumerable.Range to create the range to check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The code can look like this:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100, 1000 };
// range to check
var min = 15;
var max = 18;
Console.WriteLine(list.Any (l => Enumerable.Range(min, max - min).ToList().Contains(l)) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Output is for *[15-18]* **No** and for *[9-11]* **Yes**.

Another possibility (faster than the first one) is as @peter.petrov suggested to search in the given interval directly (using the [LINQ where clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) on the list):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100, 1000 };
// range to check
var min = 15;
var max = 18;
Console.WriteLine(list.Where (l => l > min && l < max).ToList().Count() > 0 ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Output is the same as in the first code example.

This approach can be applied to any class that implements the IEnumerable interface. One solution using a SortedList can look like this:

```
var list = new SortedList<int, int> { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 10}, {5, 100} };
// range to check
var min = 15;
var max = 18;
Console.WriteLine(list.Where (l => l.Value > min && l.Value < max).ToList().Count () > 0 ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Comment: Enumerable.Range(min, max - min) ?! Is that what I think it is? What if min=1 and max=1e10?

Comment: @peter.petrov it depends of course what kind of numbers the list will hold. My answer is for the trivial case - i assume the list contains only whole (positive) numbers. The Range method and the Contains are pretty fast for whole numbers.

Comment: My example is also for whole (positive) numbers 1 and 10000000. My point is - "is that creating a list in memory with all these numbers in there?". If they are too many, this solution would be bad; would cause a memory leak. Generally the interval could be very long; so we'd better search the other way around (check the list we already have in memory against the interval given).

Comment: @peter.petrov The solution would be slow, but it would not necessarily create a memory leak. Why should the iteration create a memory leak?

Comment: Now it doesn't because you changed it. OK, this one looks better to me.

Comment: The OP is asking about the SortedList<TKey, TValue>, not List<T>.

Comment: @drankin2112 My approach is a general one, that can be extended to any kind of class that implements the IEnumerable interface (List, SortedList, and so one).

Answer (score 1):

At first I missed the point that your list was sorted.

Seems possible, yes, in O(log N).

Suppose your interval is [A,B].
Let's say you have numbers C1, C2, ... CN in your 
list and C[K] <= C[K+1] for each K.

1) Find the minimal K1 such that C[K1] >= A
If K1 is not found, answer is "not found"
2) Find the maximal K2 such that C[K2] <= B
If K2 is not found, answer is "not found"
3) Finally, if K1<=K2 answer is "found",
otherwise the answer is "not found".

For 1) and 2) you could use binary search, I think.

So all you need to do is to code this in C#.

Answer (score 0):

`SortedList` has a method called `ContainKey()` which determines whether a SortedList object contains a specific key and is been internally determined using o(log N) since the underlined implementation is using a binary search tree. However in your case it is a range of Keys. So i recommend you to write a binary search on your range.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the fastest solution because SortedList.ContainsKey implements Dictionary.ContainsKey and it is already an O(log n) operation. Also you can bail on the first match if you are only looking for membership.

```
SortedList<uint, int> n = new SortedList<uint, int>();

private bool KeyInRange(uint rangemin, uint rangemax;){
    for (uint i=rangemin; i<=rangemax; i++)
        if(n.ContainsKey(i))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```